# where not exists in second table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to find records in subinv that do NOT have a listing in subinv table with substatus 1
when there is a listing in inv with status 1.

There is only one record per part number in `inv`, but can be several records in `subinv` with one of several status numbers.  My statement returns no rows, shows no errors, but there are records that qualify.

```
SELECT m.partnum        
  FROM inv m, 
       subinv s     
 WHERE m.status = '1'
   AND not exists (SELECT s.partnum     
                     FROM subinv s1
                    WHERE s1.substatus = '1')
```

Comment: That's a valid `EXISTS` clause, but generally you correlate with the outer query.  Also, the SELECT portion isn't evaluated - try `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 `... if you don't believe me - no divide by zero error ;)  Additionally, without join criteria that's a cartesian product...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a Cartesian product in your outer query, which is not good (especially as you don't want that join anyway), and you need to specify the part number in the EXISTS query:

```
SELECT m.partnum
  FROM inv AS m
 WHERE m.status = '1'
   AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM SubInv AS s1
         WHERE s1.substatus = '1'
           AND s1.partnum = m.partnum
       );
```

This features a correlated sub-query for the NOT EXISTS.  It would be worth checking the performance of a filtered OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT i.partnum
  FROM inv AS i
  LEFT JOIN subinv AS s ON s.partnum = i.partnum AND s.substatus = '1'
 WHERE i.status = '1'
   AND s.substatus IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN condition will generate a NULL for `s.substatus` when there is no row with `s.substatus = '1'`, and the WHERE clause only selects such rows.  Not blindingly obvious as a transform, but it might be faster than the sub-query simply because it is a join rather than a sub-query that has to be executed for each row in the main `inv` table (that satisfies `status = '1'`).

Comment: The statement **is** invalid. A *table* alias with `AS` is not allowed in Oracle. You need to use e.g. `FROM inv m` or `FROM inv i`. The rest of Jonathan's answer is correct, so just remove the `AS` and you should be fine.

Comment: WHAT A GREAT HORSE... Thanks for dropping by!  Thank you Jonathan... sans AS it works great!!!!!

Comment: That's interesting; the SQL standard permits the AS.  I was unaware that Oracle does not follow the standard.

Comment: As long as the columns compared for correlation are `NOT NULL`, [NOT IN/NOT EXISTS/LEFT JOIN - IS NULL are equivalent](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)

Comment: And ..  if one were null?  .. There are no nulls , just thinking down the road for future learning.  And by the way, Oracle does allow AS in the statement to name returned columns.

Comment: If one of the values selected with [NOT] IN is NULL, all hell breaks loose.  Don't even think about it.  AFAICR, [NOT] EXISTS is not really affected; the LEFT JOIN isn't either.